# Jtable-Without columns of edit or delete

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-plugins, html-table

I need to display a table of information on ASP.NET web forms
 I obviously want to use AJAX

I Googled plugin of Jquery-ajax to create table and found Jtable 
[jtable plugin](http://jtable.org)

It looks cool plugin !!!

but my table is only for show information,
I do not want to allow edit and delete data in a table
So I want to not show the deletion and editing columns

I was looking on Google how can not display the page and could not find
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do it just not create the actions.

```
            actions: {
                listAction: '/Demo/StudentList',
                //deleteAction: '/Demo/DeleteStudent', 
                //updateAction: '/Demo/UpdateStudent',
                //createAction: '/Demo/CreateStudent'
            },
```

See more info here: http://jtable.org/ApiReference#Actions

Comment: you can write short example how to use it?

Comment: I edited the message and correct the answer. Hope that helps.